# Why does Windows resolve all IPs of all NICs with the hostname?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012, tcpip, hostname, sockets

I´m having diferents problems with TCP/IP aplications that works through HOSTNAME. The Server where this aplications are installed(WIN Server 2012) have 4 NICs and Windows,resolve his own hostname with all IPs configured at NICs.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TEIh.png

So the TCP/IP aplications open internal sockets with diferent IPs(using HOSTNAME like address). And just I need sockets that resolve the 10.44.3.101 IP.

Are there any way to force to windows hostname to resolve only the main NIC?

PD: I had trying changing the hostname to the main IP from here HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
and worked but the aplications be gets crazy.

Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any reason you need to use Hostname? Why not use an actual DNS entry or if it only works with that particular IP that particular IP?

Comment: Just because all aplications are already release and some are olds. I can't modifies it

Comment: Try running `ipconfig /flushdns` to get rid of old rubbish.

Comment: Either that server needs a reboot to clear a lot of old rubbish (ipconfig /flushdns may not be enough) or it has a seriously fucked up network configuration.

Comment: I've reboot several times and I've make the flushdns but nothing.
In DNS cache still appear with all IPs of all interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an accumulation of old history assignments of
IP addresses to your computer,
for example by connecting to various networks and VPNs.

To clear out the useless historical data, use the command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Flushing the DNS will clear any IP addresses or other DNS records from
your local cache.

Comment: Same, after reset the server or lauch the command, It resolve all IPs. Just changing the Hostname at TCP/IP regedit value with the IP or the hostname with the domain resolve one IP. But with this solution don't work well the aplications.

Comment: I don't get the same results as yours. I think you should undo the registry changes that you did. Also test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I undid changes and runned Dism. Same issues. Is there any way to set justo one IP to resolve the hostname?? I think that this concept should be easy at SO..... Harrymc hace you several NIC interfaces and just resolve one IP?

Comment: I'm unclear here : Do you mean the IP assigned *to the host* on each of its NICs, then certainly the owner is the host and what you see is entirely natural.

Comment: Yes, I have several NICs and one aplication using the hostname option. This aplication just need the first NIC, it create socket through him. And the other NICs are for other services. When any NIC change, destroy sockets of my aplication and the app down.... For this reason I need limit the hostname IP.

Comment: Sorry, I still fail to understand the problem with hostname. You can't avoid a host being identified with its own IP (or multiple IPs in your case).